# Boost Beast async rest client : async_resolve - resolve: Host not found (authoritative)

Tags: rest, c++11, boost, boost-beast

I have the async boost rest client code. I am able to compile and run this code using Cygwin on Windows.

```
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/version.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;       // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
namespace http = boost::beast::http;    // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>

void
fail(boost::system::error_code ec, char const* what)
{
    std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}

// Performs an HTTP GET and prints the response
class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
    tcp::resolver resolver_;
    tcp::socket socket_;
    boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer_; // (Must persist between reads)
    http::request<http::empty_body> req_;
    http::response<http::string_body> res_;

public:
    // Resolver and socket require an io_context
    explicit
    session(boost::asio::io_context& ioc)
        : resolver_(ioc)
        , socket_(ioc)
    {
    }

    // Start the asynchronous operation
    void
    run(char const* host, char const* port, char const* target, int version)
    {
        // Set up an HTTP GET request message
        req_.version(version);
        req_.method(http::verb::get);
        req_.target(target);
        req_.set(http::field::host, host);
        req_.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);

        // Look up the domain name
        resolver_.async_resolve(host, port,std::bind( &session::on_resolve, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
    }

    void
    on_resolve( boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type results)
    {
        if(ec) {
            return fail(ec, "resolve");
        }

        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        boost::asio::async_connect(socket_,results.begin(),results.end(),std::bind(&session::on_connect,shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1));
    }

    void
    on_connect(boost::system::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec) {
            return fail(ec, "connect");
        }

        // Send the HTTP request to the remote host
        http::async_write(socket_, req_,std::bind(&session::on_write, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
    }

    void
    on_write( boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if(ec) {
            return fail(ec, "write");
        }

        // Receive the HTTP response
        http::async_read(socket_, buffer_, res_, std::bind( &session::on_read, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
    }

    void
    on_read(boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if(ec) {
            return fail(ec, "read");
        }
        // Write the message to standard out
        std::cout << res_ << std::endl;

        // Gracefully close the socket
        socket_.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);

        // not_connected happens sometimes so don't bother reporting it.
        if(ec && ec != boost::system::errc::not_connected) {
            return fail(ec, "shutdown");
        }
        // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully
    }
};



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Check command line arguments.
    if(argc != 4 && argc != 5)
    {
        std::cerr <<
                  "Usage: http-client-async <host> <port> <target> [<HTTP version: 1.0 or 1.1(default)>]\n" <<
                  "Example:\n" <<
                  "    http-client-async www.example.com 80 /\n" <<
                  "    http-client-async www.example.com 80 / 1.0\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    auto const host = argv[1];
    auto const port = argv[2];
    auto const target = argv[3];
    int version = argc == 5 && !std::strcmp("1.0", argv[4]) ? 10 : 11;

    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;

    // Launch the asynchronous operation
    std::make_shared<session>(ioc)->run(host, port, target, version);

    // Run the I/O service. The call will return when
    // the get operation is complete.
    ioc.run();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have a python REST Server that runs waiting for requests from this client.

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

tasks = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'title': u'Buy groceries',
        'description': u'Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol',
        'done': False
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'title': u'Learn Python',
        'description': u'Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web',
        'done': False
    }
]

@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    return jsonify({'tasks': tasks})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

I am able to run this server. The output is shown below.

```
 * Serving Flask app 'RESTServer' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployme
nt.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 409-562-797
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployme
nt.
 * Running on http://192.168.1.104:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

However when I run the REST Client, as below

```
rest_client.exe http://192.168.1.104 5000 /todo/api/v1.0/tasks
```

I get the following error

```
 resolve: Host not found (authoritative)
```

Answer (score 0):

The program expects separate arguments. It even gives you usage instructions:

```
Usage: http-client-async <host> <port> <target> [<HTTP version: 1.0 or 1.1(default)>]
Example:
    http-client-async www.example.com 80 /
    http-client-async www.example.com 80 / 1.0
```

So it looks like you AT LEAST want to remove `http://`